# can not add statistics in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

i am trying to add wilcoxon stats in my graph, but the "stat_compare_means" does not work...
i have tried both ggplot and ggplot2.

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(Rtsne)
require(ggpubr)



#excel sheet resolution, voxel size comparison
data<-read_excel("res_all.xlsx", sheet="resolution")

# transform to long format using dplyr (included in tidyverse)
data_long <- as_tibble(data) %>%
  gather(key, value,-parameter) %>%
  mutate(cohort=ifelse(grepl("per",key), "per", "val"))

# plot graph
graph <- ggplot(data_long) + 
  aes(x=parameter, y=value, fill=cohort)+
  geom_boxplot()+
  stat_compare_means(method= "wilcox.test")

graph +  ggtitle("Resolution comparison")+
  theme_minimal()
  
    
error is Error in stat_compare_means(method = "wilcox.test") : 
  could not find function "stat_compare_means"
```

is it any other way to add W and p-values in my graph?
Thank you in advance.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfp8E.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvHMO.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot a "+" after `theme_minimal()`.
Oh, and `stat_compare_means` is from `ggpubr` package, not `ggplot`. be sure you included it. Check if you have `library(ggpubr)` or `require(ggpubr)` in your R session. It is good if you can include full code and result in `sessioninfo()` for further troubleshoot.

The stat_compare_means() was introduced in ggpubr ver 0,1,3. So check the package with `?ggpubr` for the version and `lsf.str("package:ggpubr")` to list all functions inside the package.

Comment: Yes, corrected. Thank you.  But it does not change the situation with stat_compare_means.

Comment: Yes, ggpubr is also included.. forgot to mentioned that. Still not working=(